# org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation compiled by more recent version (55), this version of Java recognises class file versions up to 52

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed sonar locally to run it on my java project code. My this code is using java 8. My environment variable is also set to java 8 but I have installed Java 11 on my machine and set a environment variable SONAR_JAVA_PATH in my machine which is pointing to java 11. Here are my environment variables.

```
export SONAR_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.7.0.2747/libexec
export SONAR=$SONAR_HOME/bin
export PATH=$SONAR:$PATH

export SONAR_JAVA_PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
export PATH=$SONAR_JAVA_PATH:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

When I run following command in my root directory

```
   mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=tirebattery-orderprocessing-svcs \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=sqp_17296fe6fac85ebd5f0c0f0490b78216b5ea7140
```

It throws following error

> Execution default-cli of goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar
> failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar:
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognises class file versions up to 52.0

I am very confused about this error. In my IntelliJ how can i build code in Java 8 and run sonar on java 11 ? In few previous answers I red to edit wrapper.conf file but in MAC there is no such file created after installation of sonar through Brew.
Can anyOne kindly explain me in simple words that why this issue is happening, What is the root cause and what changes I have to make to my POM to resolve this issue. Here is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.sams.clubops.orderprocessing</groupId>
<artifactId>tbcorderprocessing</artifactId>
<version>1.8.3</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tbcorderprocessing</name>
<description>Purchase order processing services</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <azure.version>2.0.5</azure.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>2.20.1</camel.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.7.2</spring.boot.version>
    <swagger2.version>2.9.2</swagger2.version>
    <tbc-common.version>1.8.4-SNAPSHOT</tbc-common.version>
</properties>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>pangaea_releases</id>
        <name>xyz Releases</name>
        <url>http://gec-maven-nexus.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/pangaea_releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>pangaea_snapshots</id>
        <name>xyz Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://gec-maven-nexus.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/pangaea_snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Added for SQL Server Connection 12/07 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sams.event.horizon</groupId>
        <artifactId>evclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.60</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
              <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--TBC Commons dependency-->
    <dependency>

        <groupId>com.sams.clubops.tbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>tbc-common</artifactId>
        <version>${tbc-common.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        EVENT HUB EVENT PROCESSOR-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs-eph</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sams.mth</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>Dockerfile</include>
                                    <include>sshd_config</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>startup.sh</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>proxy-intranet-ref-app.conf</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/keystore</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>stage-extes-replenishment.crt</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>stage-event-horizon-eus.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>stage-event-horizon-wus.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>stage-event-horizon-station.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>event-horizon-eus.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>event-horizon-wus.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>event-horizon-station.cld.samsclub.com.cer</include>
                                    <include>stage-extes-replenishment.wal-mart.com.cer</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coveo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <displayLimit>10</displayLimit>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/sams/clubops/orderprocessing/object/**/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/sams/clubops/orderprocessing/repository/document/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*EventConsumerManager.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*EventProcessHostObjFactory.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*DotComOrdersPoLogRepo.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*OrderProcessingCosmosConfig.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <!--CHange it back to 80-->
                                        <minimum>0.83</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Java used to run SonarScanner - Java 8 in SonarQube 8.9, Java 11 in SonarQube 9.0 and higher

Either upgrade your JDK to JDK11 or downgrade SonarQube to 8.9

Comment: He says that he have both 11 and 8 installed and needs 8 in the build!  I have the same situation and would realy need a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube 9.8 has stopped supporting Scanner tool 3.9.1 for Java 8 version. So you need to use SonarQube version 8.9 or below for analysis. Or you can refer to the following but may still not work with the new Scanner tool version:

```
mvn sonar:sonar 
-Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9001/sonarqube 1
-Dsonar.java.jdkHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Reference from: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-versions-in-sonarqube/67551

Comment: He says that he have both 11 and 8 installed and needs 8 in the build! I have the same situation and would really need a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case I've just installed java 11 in addition and set JAVA_HOME to java 11 just for sonar step.

```
JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_11/ && export JAVA_HOME && mvn -X sonar:sonar -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).