# SonarQubeAnalyze@5: Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

```
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
  jdkversion: 'JAVA_HOME_11_X64'
```

I am using jdkversion attribute of this task specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sonar-qube-analyze-v5?view=azure-pipelines).

Its still not able to resolve the JDK version or path.

```
/__w/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/5.17.1/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner
Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
##[error]The process '/__w/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/5.17.1/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner' failed with exit code 1
```

The version of SonarQube server is  9.9.2

I have tried providing JAVA_HOME as an input to jdkversion attribute, but then the error is

```
##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Edit: I am using docker image openjdk:17-alpine.

Comment: Check this answer.. maybe you should update your Java - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366986/org-sonar-batch-bootstrapper-environmentinformation-compiled-by-more-recent-vers

Comment: JDK Version 11 is already installed on the image but it seems to pick JDK 8 when set as JAVA_HOME. And when set as JAVA_HOME_11_X64 it still wont pick that version.

Comment: Hi @TejasMehta, may i know if the reply below helps? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi @wadezhou-MSFT, thank you for replying. It indeed help. I downloaded and installed JDK 11 and set the Path manually.

Comment: @TejasMehta, glad to know it works and cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `env` on the machine, make sure the `jdkversion` you specified exists.

To confirm this, you can add a bash/powershell task **in pipeline** and check the result.  If you use `JAVA_HOME_11_X64`, in env it exists:

[image]

If the value is not available, **JAVA_HOME** value will be picked up instead.

[image]

Hence, please make sure the jdk has been installed, and environment has been added.

My pipeline result:

[image]